# when I open mission control flight recording file I get exception

Tags: java, bcel, jrockit

When I started flight recording for my application in java mission control it records normally and I open the .jrf file I get an exception like this:

*Could not load events from flight_recording_2013-12-11_11_28_09.jfr
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: com.sun.org.apache.bcel.internal.generic.ClassGenException: Illegal opcode detected.*

Comment: That sounds suspiciously like an incompatible JVM.  I'd check what JVM version you are using against what BCEL's requirements are.

Comment: My JVM version :
java version "1.7.0_45"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_45-b18)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.45-b08, mixed mode)

Comment: Can you edit your post to include the JVM version, BCEL library version.  Also, if you have a full stack trace, that might help.  I can't really help you beyond saying I think I understand what the problem is, but I don't know what else to ask or how to fix it.  I edited the question to include the BCEL tag with the hopes someone over there might have a clue.

Comment: Can you start a flight recording on "The JVM running Mission Control", can that recording be opened?